# I have problems with using relative and absolute paths in PHP

Tags: php

I'm doing an exercise for php classes and I have a problem with file path in my server.
I have this structure:

```
    /view/partials/header.php
    /view/img/logo.jpg
    /view/css/style.css
    /view/contact.php (include:"/view/partials/header.php")
    /index.php (include:"/view/partials/header.php")
```

all this is inside `htdocs/php` in my apache server.
So as an example of the problem is with `header.php`, inside I have reference to `logo.jpg` and `style.css`, and  I call them from `index.php` and `contact.php` which are in different folders. If I use relative path, I can make it work with index.php or contact.php and if I use absolute path neither will work, because they are inside a php folder in the server. So I move the project to the root of the server, but I was wondering If there is a way to solve this with the right path?
I use Xampp as apache and php server. Php is 8.1
I use PhpStorm as IDE
Thanks

Comment: Those are paths in the HTML generated by PHP, so why not use full URLs like "https:// 
 www.foo.com  /images/logo.jpg" ?

Comment: Paths are relative from the script the include is done from. You are using absolute paths (beginning with `/`) that means you need the whole path like `/var/www/htdocs/php/view/partials/header.php`. Just make it relative by using `./view/partials/header.php`.

Comment: You are mixing between 2 different things.

 1). The path of your web server root http//host/view/file.php
 2). The path on your server file system which can be located for example at /var/www/html/view/file.php

if you need to require / include files, do it relative to your folder, ie, require_once('./lib/my_classes.php');

other option is to define the php settings for include_path in the php.ini. this parameter defines where to search inculde/require.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path